# Java proxy applet: is such thing possible?

Tags: java, browser, proxy, applet

I am wondering whether it is technically possible to create a proxy within a java applet.

And would it then be possible to route all further browser requests through this java applet proxy?

Eg., if the user would browse to google.com, could the default behaviour be replaced by this proxy applet?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically is possible, but I think it might be very expensive and time consuming to build. You might need to do something similar as what the Juniper VPN client does. It runs an applet which run an OS specific app that changes the proxy settings, and, in you case, the same applet can run as a proxy server. The OS application also has to revert the proxy settings if it detects that the applet died or was closed. In the case of Juniper, it changes the system hosts file instead of the proxy settings.

As for Mat concern: the user will get a few pop ups telling her to be SUPER sure of running the app and installing the OS app... again, in the same way that happens with Juniper :)

#### EDIT

It depends how many OSs / browsers you want to support. In worst case scenario you'll need an app to set and rollback the system proxy settings for Windows, Mac, Linux (I don't even know if there's system wide configuration for the proxy configuration). Then (as far as I remember) the way to sign an applet for IE is different than for all the other browsers.

What I'm trying to say is that it's not a weekend job, it could easily take a couple of months to code and have plenty of issues with certain combination of OS / browsers.

Comment: Could you explain why this would be so technically challenging? Simply requesting full permissions and then setting the OS's proxy settings does not sound all that difficult, or is it?

Comment: AFAIK, these VPN connectors require installed OS drivers (you get prompted to install the drivers if you don't have them already in most cases). The "code" that does the proxying is not in the brower, it's OS level drivers (virtual network adapters). So even if technically an applet or ActiveX actives the VPN, I don't think you can do that with _just_ the applet.

Comment: @Mat there is no inbuild proxy in Windows or Linux that can be configured then?

Comment: @Mat you don't need a driver to configure a proxy, you just need to tell the OS to use a proxy, take as an example Charles Proxy (which is built in Java), when you run it, it changes the system level proxy setting (at least in mac and windows). @Tom Windows and Mac have a system wide proxy configuration, I don't know about Linux.

Comment: indeed, I was just talking about the VPN connectors I know about. Running a "system-wide" proxy can certainly be done, but at the OS level, not in the browser - which is I think the point Tom was asking about - run that in browser directly with an applet. @Tom: there is no standard proxy management interface in Linux in general. Each distribution and desktop environment has its thing pretty much.